# Run Wireguard as a client on Win10 with WSL2

Tags: linux-kernel, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wireguard

When attempting to run a Wireguard client in a Docker container or on WSL2 itself you will run into issues such as:

```
2022-04-27 17:15:45,035 DEBG 'start-script' stderr output:
[#] ip -4 rule add table main suppress_prefixlength 0

2022-04-27 17:15:45,036 DEBG 'start-script' stderr output:
[#] sysctl -q net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark=1

2022-04-27 17:15:45,036 DEBG 'start-script' stderr output:
[#] iptables-restore -n

2022-04-27 17:15:45,247 DEBG 'start-script' stderr output:
iptables-restore v1.8.7 (legacy): unknown option "--save-mark"
Error occurred at line: 5
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.

2022-04-27 17:15:45,247 DEBG 'start-script' stderr output:
[#] resolvconf -d wg0 -f

2022-04-27 17:15:45,251 DEBG 'start-script' stderr output:
could not detect a useable init system

2022-04-27 17:15:45,267 DEBG 'start-script' stderr output:
[#] ip -4 rule delete table 51820

2022-04-27 17:15:45,270 DEBG 'start-script' stderr output:
[#] ip -4 rule delete table main suppress_prefixlength 0

2022-04-27 17:15:45,283 DEBG 'start-script' stderr output:
[#] ip link delete dev wg0

2022-04-27 17:15:45,456 DEBG 'start-script' stdout output:
[warn] WireGuard interface failed to come 'up', exit code is '1'
```

or you see this

```
sh-5.1# wg-quick up wg0
[#] ip link add wg0 type wireguard
[#] wg setconf wg0 /dev/fd/63
[#] ip -4 address add 10.8.130.27 dev wg0
[#] ip link set mtu 1420 up dev wg0
[#] wg set wg0 fwmark 51820
[#] ip -4 route add 0.0.0.0/0 dev wg0 table 51820
[#] ip -4 rule add not fwmark 51820 table 51820
[#] ip -4 rule add table main suppress_prefixlength 0
[#] sysctl -q net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark=1
[#] iptables-restore -n
iptables-restore v1.8.7 (legacy): unknown option "--save-mark"
Error occurred at line: 5
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
[#] ip -4 rule delete table 51820
[#] ip -4 rule delete table main suppress_prefixlength 0
[#] ip link delete dev wg0
sh-5.1#
```

This is the same error message but narrowed down.

Answer (score 4):

Credits to https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/jk4x24/is_there_a_way_to_run_wireguard_within_wsl2/gah860j/

The culprit is that WSL2 kernel isn't compiled with necessary netfilter targets or matches for iptables or nftables to work.

You can verify this by running for example:

```
$ iptables -C INPUT -m connmark --mark 0x10/0x10 -j DROP
iptables v1.8.4 (legacy): Couldn't load match `connmark':No such file or directory
```

The Linux kernel that came with my WSL installation does not have the `CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CONNMARK` flag.

First you need to get the kernel source code used by Microsoft. You can get it from their github page with this command:

```
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel.git
```

Copy the current kernel configuration with:

```
zcat /proc/config.gz > .config
```

Use sed to search and replace

```
sed -i 's/# CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CONNMARK is not set/CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CONNMARK=y/g' .config
```

Now you can compile the kernel with the right flag enabled. Use:

```
yes "" | make -j $(nproc)
```

`yes ""` will function as you pressing enter and fill in defaults for the configurations that was not specified.
`$(nproc)` is the number of threads your CPU can handle.

Next you have to copy the newly compiled kernel image to the Windows side. You can copy it using this:

```
cp arch/x86_64/boot/bzImage /mnt/c/Users/<user>/bzImage
```

Tell WSL to use the new kernel by adding a configuration file:

In the folder `/mnt/c/Users/<user>/` or `C:\Users\<user>\` there should be a `.wslconfig` file with the content:

```
[wsl2]
kernel=C:\\Users\\<user>\\bzImage
```

Close WSL and shut it down from a `cmd` prompt with:

```
wsl --shutdown
```

Then start wsl with `wsl`. With `uname -r` you can see you are now using a new kernel.

Now the above error in question should be gone and hopefully your Wireguard client is working.

Comment: How can we check if our WSL2 installation is or isn't compiled with the necessary things?

Comment: See first code block in answer @IMTheNachoMan